# VS compiler does not create inner folders for objects

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, makefile

VS compiler generates the folder where the objects should be created:

```
OBJS=obj\class_A.obj
obj\class_A.obj : class_A.cpp class_A.h
```

When generating the above - folder obj is created.

**But**: In case inner folders are used:

```
OBJS=obj\INNER\class_A.obj
obj\INNER\class_A.obj : class_A.cpp class_A.h
```

Trying to build the above, causes error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'obj\INNER\class_A.obj': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?
Is this a VS compiler bug?

This, btw, compiles well with Cygwin.